# How to visualize an interaction from a GLMM: use whole model to obtain predicted values or just factors in the interaction?

Tags: data-visualization, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, interaction, interpretation

I need to plot an interaction between two continuous factors for interpretation. I am using the wireframe function in the lattice package and plotting the predicted values from the model with the best fit. The model looks somewhat like this:

```
out<-lmer(response~apples+pears+strawberry+mangoes+(mangoes)^2+strawberry:mangoes+  
(1|id),family="poisson")
```

However, if I use the predicted values from the whole model the wireframe's surface is different than if I only use the predicted values from a model that only contains the variables that interact (omitting also the quadratic term):

```
out<-lmer(response~strawberry+mangoes+strawberry:mangoes+(1|id),family="poisson")
```

The difference is big enough to cause concern, and I would like to ask which method gives the best interpretation of the data, and why are the surfaces so different?